# How to copy multiple range to the exact same location in another sheet using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy multiple range  from one sheet to another sheet.

I have tried using the getRangelist function but it seems it was not designed for that purpose

```
var rangeList = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeList(['B2:i8','B10:i16','B18:i24', 'B26:i32', 'B34:i40']);
var copyrange =  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("ENTRATE MAIN 2")
    .getRangeList(['B2:i8', 'B10:i16','B18:i24', 'B26:i32', 'B34:i40']);
  rangeList.copyTo(rangelist);
```

Any smart way of copying the multiple range to a another sheet will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you consider a "smart way"?

Comment: less code - preferably

Comment: Are you open to use the Google Sheets Advanced Service (Google Sheets API)?

Comment: never used it before

Comment: Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced

Comment: I think that @Rubén's comment will be useful for your situation. If you want to use the copy of values using the range list, how about this GAS library? This library is like the wrapper for enhancing the range list using Sheets API. https://github.com/tanaikech/RangeListApp If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a RangeList is a collection of ranges you have to loop through the collection and copy each range.

```
function test () {
  try {
    var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var rlist = sheet.getRangeList(["A1:A5", "B7:B10", "C12:C16"]);
    sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    for( var i=0; i<rlist.getRanges().length; i++ ) {
      var r1 = rlist.getRanges()[i];
      var r2 = sheet.getRange(r1.getA1Notation());
      r1.copyTo(r2);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```